# How to run SCORM.zip file URL in objective c

Tags: objective-c, scorm

How to run SCROM.zip file URL in objective c?
I download the SCORM API zip file and course zip file. But it's nothing to show index.html of course zip file. How can I run this course zip file with SCORM API zip in Objective C?

Comment: What are you trying to do, what have you tried, and what results did you get? More details means better answers. [Edit] the question and be as clear as possible,

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't. First you can't "run" a zip file as it isn't runnable. You need to unzip it, and in the SCORM case what is inside will be a manifest file along with HTML files and their supporting assets. A particular HTML file (determined by the contents of the manifest file, `imsmanifest.xml`) will need to be rendered in a browser context, specifically one that supports a full JavaScript runtime. Additionally the SCORM RTE will need to be made available in that JS runtime.

See https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/ for a lot more about SCORM.